# Doctrine 2: cannot set OneTo Many relation correctly

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I have 2 entities: Interview and Comment. Interview has one to many unidirectional relation with Comment.

Here is my yaml mapping file for Comment:

```
Entities\Comment:
  type: entity
  table: Comment
  repositoryClass: Repositories\CommentRepository

  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    parentid:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      column: parentid
    isactive:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      column: isactive
    isremoved:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      column: isremoved
    removaldate:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      column: removaldate
    user_name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: user_name
    user_email:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: user_email
    user_avatar:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: user_avatar
    comment:
      type: text
      nullable: false
      column: comment
    creationdate:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
      column: creationdate
    rating:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
```

Here is my yaml mapping file for Interview:

```
Entities\Interview:
  type: entity
  table: Interview
  repositoryClass: Repositories\InterviewRepository

  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    isremoved:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      column: isremoved
    removaldate:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      column: removaldate
    creationdate:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
      column: creationdate
    rating:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
    anonstitle:
      type: string
      length: 1000
      nullable: false
      column: anonstitle
    anons:
      type: text
      nullable: false
      column: anons
    anonsphoto:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
      column: anonsphoto
    interviewtitle:
      type: string
      length: 1000
      nullable: false
      column: interviewtitle
    interview:
      type: text
      nullable: true
      column: interview
    interviewphoto:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
      column: interviewphoto
  manyToMany:
    comments:
      targetEntity: Comment
      joinTable:
        name: interviews_comments
        joinColumns:
          interview_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          comment_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            unique: true
```

So after loading schema to database, i have 3 tables. 2 of them are tables of entities, one is for relation and it has just 2 columns: interview_id, comment_id. But after persisting Comment objects for some Interview i dont see anything in join table. Can't find out why.

Comment: please post controller code, the update or create actions, wherever you are having the troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interview has one to many unidirectional relation with Comment.

No, because you defined this relation as `manyToMany` in `Entities\Interview`, not unidirectional `oneToMany` in owning side.

`ManyToMany` mapping requeres a join table. Because one `Interview` can have many `Comment` and one `Comment` can have many `Interview`. This problem cannot be sloved with additional attributes in database tables, so the additional mapping table is created.

**Solution**:
If you want to have a one `Interview` with many `Comment`, but one `Comment` have one `Interview`, you have to correct the mapping in yaml `Entities\Interview` to `oneToMany` without `joinTable` (as you defined and it is created).

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table this page of official documentations says that one-to-many unidirectional relation must be defined via ManyToMany keyword. It creates join tables, but i don't know how to manipulate with these join tables 'cause when i add comments or interview i have comment and interview tables filled. But no data in join tables.

Comment: Nope.

> A unidirectional one-to-many association >> can be << mapped through a join table.

But not must be.

Comment: ok, u are right. But how must i manipulate with these join tables? must i myself fill them or system must fill them while i add comments or interviews?